# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

When I try to pass rowNum = 2 and colNum = 2 into the 2d array I get an exception when it should be returning false, can somebody help me with this?

```
    public boolean addPassenger(String passName, int rowNum, int colNum) {
    boolean check = false;
     System.out.println("row num: " + rowNum + " column num: " + colNum);
     System.out.println("row length: " + p.length + " column length: " + p[0].length);

    if (rowNum <= p.length && colNum <= p[0].length && rowNum >= 0 && colNum >= 0 && p[rowNum][colNum].getName().equals("")) {

        p[rowNum][colNum] = new Passenger(passName, f);
        check = true;

    } else if (rowNum >= p.length || colNum >= p[0].length || !p[rowNum][colNum].getName().equals("")) {

        check = false;
    } else {
        check = false;
    }

    return check;
}
```

Here is some output

```
              run:
        Welcome to blank Airlines
        Enter a flight number:
        R62
        Enter the number of rows:
        2
        Enter the number of seats per row:
        2
        Enter add, remove, seats, list, or quit:
        add
        Enter passenger name, row, and seat:
        me 0 0
        row num: 0 column num: 0
        row length: 2 column length: 2
        Passenger me was added.
        Enter add, remove, seats, list, or quit:
        seats
         |         0||         1|
        0|        me||          |
        1|          ||          |
        Enter add, remove, seats, list, or quit:
        add
        Enter passenger name, row, and seat:
        you 2 2
        row num: 2 column num: 2
        row length: 2 column length: 2
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
                at csc212hw06.Plane.addPassenger(Plane.java:34)
                at csc212hw06.Main.main(Main.java:61)
        Java Result: 1
```

Here is the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at csc212hw06.Plane.addPassenger(Plane.java:34)
at csc212hw06.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Java Result: 1
```

If anyone has some suggestions it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Use a debugger, which is what you are basically asking us to do for you

Comment: You check `rowNum <= p.length` and access `p[rowNum]` - what might be the problem there? (Similarly for `colNum`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (rowNum <= p.length && colNum <= p[0].length && rowNum >= 0 && colNum >= 0 && p[rowNum][colNum].getName().equals("")) {
```

Should be `rowNum < p.length && colNum < p[0].length`, not `rowNum <= p.length && colNum <= p[0].length`. In an `n`-sized array, valid indexes are `[0,n-1]`, which means that indexing `n` will give out-of-bounds errors.